# How to filter out results contains certain string in vim regex?

Tags: regex, vim

Suppose I have a bunch of code, the format is like verilog `input/output (wire {signal_name}(,)`.

```
input  wire aaa,
input  bbb,               // "wire" can be omitted 
input  wire ccc           // the comma can be omitted
input  wire ddd_0,
output ddd_1  
output wire ddd_1,
output wire EEE_E,
```

And I want to capture the signal name such as `aaa`, `bbb` ... `EEE_E`
My regex is:

```
/\v(((input)|(output))[ ]+(wire)*[ ]*)@<=([_0-9a-zA-Z]+)
```

But it seems that `"wire"` itself also matchs this pattern and will be captured.
I can use the `'\n'` '",\n"' to make sure no `"wire"` will be captured because there is never `'\n'` or '",\n"' behind `"wire"`. But is there any general method to filter out certain strings or certain patterns in vim regex?

```
outcomes.filter_out("wire")
```

---

Maybe I need a simpler example?
Suppose I have a bunch of "word" composed by `{'a'-'z', '0'-'9', '_', '$', '%'}`

```
11 apple pear banan0 wire _work m$oney && books wire word air 22
```

If I use
`/\v(\s|^)@<=([a-z]*)\ze(\s|$)`,

I got all "pure" words:
`apple pear wire books wire word air`.

But, what can I do if I don't want `wire` matched, only:
`apple pear books word air`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the words `apple` `pear` `books` `word` `air` or `wires` in the sentence:

> 11 apple pear banan0 wire _work m$oney && books wire word air 22

You can use lookarounds and `\v` for very magic mode

```
\v\S@<!(wire\S@!)@![a-z]+\S@!
```

**Explanation**

- `\v` Very magic mode
- `\S@<!` Negative lookbehind, assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `(wire\S@!)` Negative lookahead, assert not the word `wire` directly to the right followed by a whitespace boundary
- `[a-z$%]+` Match 1 or more of the listed character in the character class
- `\S@!` Negative lookahead, assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[image]

You can extend this mechanism to match the input/output examples in the first part of your question.

Note that to see the highlights as in the attached image, you can run `:set hls`

Answer (score 1):

```
\(in\|out\)put\s\+\(wire\s*\)*\zs\([^, ]\+\)
```

seems to do what you want (or at least what I think you want):

[image: capture]

As for your question:

> But is there any general method to filter out certain strings or certain patterns in vim regex?

Your example doesn't seem to involve regex at all so I am not sure what it is you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you! This sames correct. I got a new example for the question.

Comment: All you are showing is a regular expression without context. Is it a search with `/`? A substitution? Some vimscript?

Comment: Searched with Vim `/`.  In   `/\v(\s|^)@<=([a-z]*)\ze(\s|$)` ,  `\v` means "very magic mode", you don't need to add `\` before ```( ) @```  or some other symbols to use their functions after adding ```\v```.